# Lie group O(3, 2)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've looking for the matrices of the O(3, 2) Lie group or, instead of them, the structure constants of its algebra $\mathfrak o(3, 2)$ but I've not been successfull. Does anyone know them or can suggest me a book with these contents?

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what is meant here is the (real) orthogonal group of matrices which leave a symmetric bilinear form of signature $(3,2)$ invariant. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group. This gives a description in terms of matrices as (in this case)

$O(3,2) = \lbrace A \in M_5(\Bbb R) \text{ such that } gA^{tr}g =A^{-1} \text{ where } g = diag[1,1,1,-1,-1] \rbrace$

About good book references, I have found S. Helgasson, *Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces* as well as Onishchik/Vinberg, *Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups* very helpful.

---

By the way, since a signature $(3,2)$ implies a Witt index of $2$, which is maximal in a five-dimensional space, I'm quite sure that this is actually the "**split**" orthogonal group of dimension 5, with root system $B_2$. So the structure constants would be the same (if given as integers, e.g. for a Chevalley basis) as those for the complex group $O(5, \Bbb C)$.

---

Added 17-X-2018:

I can offer two matrix representations of the **split** Lie **algebra** $\mathfrak{so}_{3,2}(k)$ over an arbitrary characteristic zero field $k$. However, both use a different normalisation than above: Namely, if to represent the bilinear form, we do not use the above diagonal matrix, but the matrix (**EDIT**: corrected)

$G := \pmatrix{0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1}$

(which is equivalent, but amounts to a different choice of basis), then the (10-dimensional) Lie algebra is given by

$\lbrace \pmatrix{a&b&0&e&g\\
c&d&-e&0&h\\
0&f&-a&-c&i\\
-f&0&-b&-d&j\\
-i&-j&-g&-h&0\\} : a, ..., j \in k \rbrace$

and you can pick a letter, set that one $=1$, the others $=0$, and then compute the relations between them; there you have structure constants for that basis. (I found that in [my thesis](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Memoires/2017/151/html/smf_mem-ns_151.php), p.85.)

On the other hand, Bourbaki gives yet another normalisation for that split Lie algebra in exercise 4 to paragraph 13 of chapter VIII of the *Lie Groups and Algebras* book. There, they instead write the bilinear form with the matrix

$H := \pmatrix{0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0}.$

Using this, it describes the Lie algebra as those $5\times 5$-matrices which are skew-symmetric w.r.t. the second diagonal, i.e.

$\lbrace \pmatrix{a&b&c&d&0\\
e&f&g&0&-d\\
h&i&0&-g&-c\\
j&0&-i&-f&-b\\
0&-j&-h&-e&-a\\} : a, ..., j \in k \rbrace$

Again, one can compute the structure constants for the obvious ten basis elements here. Actually, if you do that for either of these two matrix sets, I would be interested in seeing them.

Comment: That's the group I'm looking for, but the problem with that Wikipedia page is that it doesn't provide matrices or structure constantes, but thanks for the clarification

Comment: Well it does give a matrix representation. Do you want a 100% explicit representation, as in "all $5\times 5$-matrices $A$ such that the entries ..."? I am not sure that would be more helpful than the equation, given there, $gA^{tr}g =A^{-1}$? As for structure constants, I'll look into it (but of course they depend on a choice of basis).

Comment: I asked for the all 5x5 matrices in order to deduce the algebra by the commutator of the matrices. Thanks for trying to find the structure constants!

Comment: Let's see if I understand your answer. You have given me 2 possible ways to write the 5x5 matrices of the algebra of $\mathfrak so(3, 2)$ not for the diagonal bilinear form $g = diag[1 1 1 -1 -1]$ but for those that you call $G$ and $H$. These new ones are related to $g$ by a basis change, i.e., $G = PgP^{-1}$ (similarly for $H$). Therefore, I can obtain the algebra of $SO(3, 2)$ associated to $g$ not $G$ or $H$ by these $P, P^{-1}$ matrices, that is $P(your-matrix-for-{\mathfrak so(3, 2)})P^{-1}$; and this will be equal to $o(3, 2)$. Is this right?