# Is there a canonical form for the matrices of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(2n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

I was given in class the following definitions:

**Definition 1** 
The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is defined as the subspace of the matrices $ A \in \mathfrak{gl}(n)$ such that $AJ + JA^{t} = 0$, with $J \in \mathfrak{gl}(n)$ and

$J= \begin{pmatrix}  
    0 & 0 & ....& 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & .... & 1 & 0\\
    .. & .. & .. & ..& .. \\ 
    0 & 1 & ....& 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & ....& 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

In other words, $J$ has the secondary diagonal with all entries equal to 1 and all the other entries are zero.

**Definition 2** The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}(2n)$ is defined as the subspace of the matrices $A \in \mathfrak{gl}(2n)$ such that $AJ + JA^{t} = 0$, with $J \in \mathfrak{gl}(2n)$ and

$J= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 &...& 0 & 0 &...& 1 \\
     &   &  .  &.   & &. \\
    . &   &  .  &.   &  &. \\
    0 &...& 0 & 1 &...& 0 \\  
     0 &...& -1 & 0 &...& 0 \\
    . &   &  .  &.   & &. \\
    . &   &  .  &.   &  &. \\
    -1 &...& 0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

In other words $J$ has the secondary diagonal with a sequence of n entries equal to 1 and a sequence of n entries equal to -1. All the other entries are zero.

Now, is there a standard way in which such matrices are presented?  For example, I know that a matrix $A \in \mathfrak{sp}(4)$ can have the following form:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    t_1 & a & z & x  \\
    b & t_2 & y & z  \\
    u & s & -t_2 & -a  \\
    t & u & -b & -t_1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

What is the analogue form for the matrices $A \in \mathfrak{so}(4)$ (or for $\mathfrak{so}(n)$)? Is the following correct, for $\mathfrak{so}(4)$?

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    t_1 & a & z & x  \\
    b & t_2 & y & z  \\
    u & s & t_2 & a  \\
    t & u &  b & t_1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

Does it mean that in the general case for $n$, the matrix $A$ would be like the case $n=4$, but with random rows separating the two upper blocks from the two lower blocks?

Comment: Your presentation of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is unusual.  Typically, we say $A \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$ iff we have $A = -A^T$; I don't think that your version is equivalent.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ doesn't work for $n = 3$: The matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ has $A^t = -A$ but $AJ + JA^t\not = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So in the case of the definition $A^t = -A$, what would a standard presentation be?

Comment: Those are standard definitions for the *split forms* of those Lie algebras. So e.g. over the complex numbers you can work with these, and the presentations will be helpful to see the roots etc., but e.g. over $\mathbb R$ one usually calls $\mathfrak{so}_n$ the *compact* form, that one is indeed given e.g. by the choice $J=Id$ (giving $A^t=-A$), and is not isomorphic to this one.

Comment: The Lie algebras as you define them, with one slight change for the case $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$, are spelled out and discussed in volume VIII  §13 of Bourbaki's treatise on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras (types $B_n, C_n$ and $D_n$). Again, these are the **split** forms. Over complex numbers, this is redundant information, but over the reals, the standard notation e.g. for an even-dimensional orthogonal one would rather be $\mathfrak{so}(n/2, n/2)$. Compare also my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953385/96384.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out, by working with the definition, the generic matrix $A \in \mathfrak{so}(4)$:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    t_1 & a & z & 0  \\
    b & t_2 & 0 & -z  \\
    u & 0 & -t_2 & -a  \\
    0 & -u &  -b & -t_1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: As said in comments to the question, if the entries are supposed to be $\in \mathbb R$, this Lie algebra should **not** be called $\mathfrak{so}(4)$, but $\mathfrak{so}(2,2)$, as it belongs to the special indefinite orthogonal group with respect to a form of signature $(2,2)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group); whereas over the real numbers, $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ is virtually always understood to be the one belonging to the compact group $SO(4)$, the transformations orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product -- and these are not isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, the entries in my case are meant to be complex (I'm working with algebraically close fields). Thanks for your clarification anyway :)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Once again I came back to this problem and I encountered a new representation for $\mathfrak{sp}(4)$ which is the set of all $4x4$ matrices $A$ such that $JA = -A^{t}J$, where $J$ is a $4x4$ block matrix, where the upper-right  $2x2$ block is the $Id$ (the identity matrix), the lower left block is $-Id$ and the remaining two blocks are null. How would you prove this is an equivalent representation with respect to the one written in the question?

Comment: All skew-symmetric matrices over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ are congruent, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1682385/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719021/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388750/96384, and Bourbaki *Algebra* ch. 9 §5 for a generalisation to commutative rings. In your case, a relatively obvious base change matrix is $\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0}$ (you flip the third and the fourth basis vector). For the matrices of the Lie algebra, you then follow the procedure in the links at the end of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3771729/96384.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!